# Weka cant match test and train set

Tags: data-mining, weka

Train and test set are not compatible in weka!
What problem they has same header and same attribute type and number.

This is [train](http://mir.cr/1HVGXCRA) and [test](http://mir.cr/XQFCBIAC) set

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Weka's native data format is ".arff".  When you load your .csv files, Weka will convert them.  **The header of the converted files will not be the same.**  If you save both the train and test set as .arff from Weka, and open them in a simple text editor you will see the difference.

The difference is because the nominal values in Attribute UNS appear in a different order.  You can simply copy the header from either the train or test .arff and paste it in place of the other.